# How can I retrieve the controller and action name from the route name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

After I register a route, how can I retrieve controller and action name what belongs to the specified route name?

For example if I register this route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Category",
                "C/{id}/{urlText}",
                new { controller = "Catalog", action = "ProductListByCategoryId" }
);
```

I want to retrieve the controller name "Catalog" and  the action name "ProductListByCategoryId" by the route name parameter "Category".

I need this for a html helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper,
                                string name,
                                string routeName,
                                object routeValues)
{
    string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    object currentId = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"];

    string actionName = ""; //This is what I want to specify
    string controllerName = "";  //This is what I want to specify
    var propertyInfo = routeValues.GetType().GetProperty("id");
    var id = propertyInfo.GetValue(routeValues, null);

    if (actionName == currentAction &&
        controllerName == currentController &&
        id == currentId)
    {
        return helper.RouteLink(name, routeName, routeValues, new { @class = "active" });
    }
    else
    {
        return helper.RouteLink(name, routeName, routeValues, new { @class = "active" });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this given only a route name. The reason for that is that a route could match for multiple controllers and actions. What you could do is to retrieve the current controller and action from the `HttpContext`:

```
RouteData rd = HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
string currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
string currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
```

Comment: And with routeName and routeValues can I reteive the controller and the action name?

Comment: Where do you want to retrieve this information? From a controller action? If you have the route values, isn't it because you are already inside the controller action that matched this route? What are you trying to achieve exactly? I have updated my answer with an example that allows you to retrieve the current controller and action names from the `HttpContext`.

Comment: In a HtmlHelper extension to determine that a link what I create with it, has the same controller, action and id as the generated page or not.

Comment: The code I have shown should give you the current controller and action that was used to render the view from the HttpContext that have access to in your helper.

Comment: I extended my question with the helper source.

Comment: Adding the controller and the action name to the helper parameters should resolve my problem, but it is not too elegant.